# Unable to get DeclaredField "usr_paths " via java reflection 17.0.3

Tags: java, reflection, java-17

I'm trying to get usr_paths, but the console gives an error that it can't find this field, what should I do?

```
public static void addDir(String s) throws IOException {
    try {
        Field field = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("usr_paths"); // there's a error here !!
        field.setAccessible(true);
        String[] paths = (String[]) field.get(null);
        for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
            if (s.equals(paths[i])) {
                return;
            }
        }
        String[] tmp = new String[paths.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(paths, 0, tmp, 0, paths.length);
        tmp[paths.length] = s;
        field.set(null, tmp);
        System.setProperty("java.library.path", System.getProperty("java.library.path") + File.pathSeparator + s);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IOException("Failed to get permissions to set library path");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new IOException("Failed to get field handle to set library path");
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason is mundane, you get an exception telling you that there is no such field, because there is no such field. But not only has this field renamed and moved to a different class, it’s `static final` now, which means that a simple `setAccessible(true)` won’t be enough to make it writable.

Comment: This hack to set java.library.path works on older JVM only. You should consider what your code is trying to achieve and whether you can workaround this using `System.load(String filename)` or by setting VM startup `-Djava.library.path=xyz`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't exist but if it did the answer would be this:

```
Field field;
try {
    Method m = Class.class.getDeclaredMethod("getDeclaredFields0", boolean.class);
    m.setAccessible(true);
    for (Field f : (Field[]) m.invoke(ClassLoader.class, false)) {
        if (f.getName().equals("usr_paths")) {

            Method copy = Field.class.getDeclaredMethod("copy");
            forceAccessible(copy);

            field = (Field) copy.invoke(f);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {}
```